# Does WinRT development support NuGet packages?

Tags: nuget, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Can we use NuGet packages in developing WinRT Metro style applications using XAML/C# or HTML/JS/CSS?

Comment: NuGet is an add-in, has nothing to do with the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NuGet currently supports WinRT libraries for deployment in your project for .NET 4.5 -- we're working with the team to get greater support there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 2 parts articles on how integrate Nuget Dev with WinRT component :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/08/27/packaging-a-windows-store-apps-component-with-nuget-part-1.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/09/02/packaging-a-windows-store-apps-component-with-nuget-part-2.aspx

I Hope this could help you !

Sebastien